# What am I doing wrong in this date formatter

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdateformatter

```
 NSDate *date=[[NSDate alloc] init];
    NSDateFormatter *dfLocal=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dfLocal setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    date=[dfLocal dateFromString:@"2011-09-22"];
    NSLog(@"the date is %@",date);
```

this is my code and gives the output as..

```
2012-04-02 18:13:45.338 TimeProblem[2656:207] the date is 2011-09-21 18:30:00 +0000
```

why is it appending this.. 18:30:00 +0000 to the end..? I just want it to be as 00:00:00 +0000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use below:

```
NSDate *date=[[NSDate alloc] init];
NSDateFormatter *dfLocal=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dfLocal setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
[dfLocal setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];
date=[dfLocal dateFromString:@"2011-09-22"];

NSLog(@"the date is %@",date);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are in GMT+5.30 . That is why you get the time offset. It is a timeZone problem. Adding this line would solve the problem.

```
 [dfLocal setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
```

Answer (score 0):

hi you want to get date and time then use like this .

```
[dfLocal setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
```

hope this will help you.